# How can (GNU/BSD) libc macros be safe?

Tags: c, glibc, libc, c89

Upon reimplementing some *libc* functions (in my school’s “personal” library project called [`libft`](https://bitbucket.org/Diti/libft)), I got the idea of implementing some as macros, like so:

```
#define ft_isalnum(c)  (ft_isalpha(c) || ft_isdigit(c))
#define ft_isalpha(c)  (ft_isupper(c) || ft_islower(c))
#define ft_isascii(c)  (((c) >= 0) && ((c) <= 0177))
#define ft_isdigit(c)  (((c) >= '0') && ((c) <= '9'))
#define ft_islower(c)  (((c) >= 'a') && ((c) <= 'z'))
#define ft_isprint(c)  (((c) >= 0040) && ((c) <= 0176))
#define ft_isspace(c)  ((((c) >= 0x09) && ((c) <= 0x0d)) || ((c) == 0x20))
#define ft_isupper(c)  (((c) >= 'A') && ((c) <= 'Z'))
```

However, I soon found out that instructions like [`ft_isspace(s[--len])`](https://bitbucket.org/Diti/libft/raw/e593217d7b663dbbd516bda2c942a9277dccf82e/srcs/str/ft_strtrim.c) become broken, because the `len` variable gets decremented three times. So I had to make actual functions instead of macros.

I know that macros are unsafe. But I see that GNU/BSD libc implementations of the `is*(3)` character tests are macros. **How do they make their macros safe?**

I am not allowed (at school) to use functions I have not implemented myself (except `malloc(3)`, `free(3)`, and a few system calls such as `write(2)`. And I presume that calling a function just to test an ASCII character is rather inefficient.

Thanks.

Comment: "I am not allowed (at school) to use functions I have not implemented myself." - Seems like it would be very difficult to write any working code following that rule.

Comment: The BSD macros aren't "safe" either. No preprocessor macros are.

Comment: "I am not allowed (at school) to use functions I have not implemented myself." - it's weird for a school to actually teach Not Invented Here Syndrome.

Comment: As for the inefficiency of functions, you might ask the compiler to make them [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is C89. Inline functions are C99.

Comment: There are ways to efficiently implement most macros without evaluating the argument twice. They are still unsafe, but for different reasons.

Comment: Inline functions were introduced into the standard in C99. That doesn't mean that compilers implementing the earlier standard don't have inline functions as vendor extensions. You can easily test for that with preprocessor macros.

Comment: Oh dear, do you really have a separate file for every function?

Comment: Why don't you look at the include files to see how the macro versions of is* are set up to only evaluate the argument once?

Comment: @mpez0 I obviously did so before asking the question on here. Checking the header file didn't help much, the macros are "obfuscated" with other macros that I don't know where to search the definition from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case for the functions in ctype.h both linux and BSDs look up the value in an array that contains a bitmask for all the valid values the functions can be called with - [0,255]. Each of the functions simply index the array with their argument and check if the particular bit you're testing for is set. That's how they only evaluate the argument once.

It might look something like this:

```
#define C_ALPHA 0x01
#define C_NUM 0x02
...
int ctype_array[256] = { ..., /* offset for 'A' */C_ALPHA|C_PRINT|C_UPPER, ...};
#define isalnum(c) (ctype_array[(c)] & (C_ALPHA|C_NUM))
```

In a more general case for all macros a trick is to do:

```
#define foo(x) do { int _x = (x); do_something_with(_x, twice(_x)); } while (0)
```

Of course this construct can't return anything (the do-while construct is so that this is a single statement that doesn't break when put as a single statement in an if/for/while statement without brackets). There are compiler extensions that allow macros like this to be implemented safely and returning a value.

In general, I would recommend going for inline functions or just use normal functions. Function call overhead isn't that high on modern CPUs and in large programs you might even get substantial speedups on a macro level by wasting less cache for code. Get your code correct first, then think about speeding it up while measuring if your inlines are actually doing anything at all.

Comment: Neat! What is the `twice(_x)` function supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Diti It was just a clever way of writing "do something with x twice".